# "To pay slightly more is..." vs "Paying slightly more is..."

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

Could I say both of the sentences below?

> To pay slightly more is a necessary evil for motorists...

vs

> Paying slightly more is a necessary evil for motorists...

When should I use infinite and when gerund?

Comment: They mean the same. The choice is yours.